# How to add column to an existing SQL Server table based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, case

I want to add a column to an existing table based on the condition of 3 columns in the table like the example below.

I have 3 columns :

- EXPIRED
- pending
- on_the_go

where each column had as value the ID number from another table of the corresponding value (expired value is 1)(pending value is 2)...

What I want is to add a column called `status` that combine all these 3 columns into 1

I tried to use `CASE WHEN` but that did not work as expected:

```
SELECT 
    EXPIRED, pending, on_the_go,
    CASE EXPIRED
        WHEN 1 THEN 1
    END AS status_type,
    CASE pending
        WHEN 2 THEN 2
    END AS status_type,
    CASE on_the_go
        WHEN 3 THEN 3
    END AS status_type,
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_exchange_activities 
FROM 
    card 
GROUP BY 
    EXPIRED, pending, on_the_go
```

| EXPIRED | pending | on_the_go | status_type | status_type | status_type | number_of_exchange_activities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | NULL | 2 | NULL | 550 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | NULL | NULL | 3 | 320 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | NULL | NULL | 310 |

This is what I expected to get:

| EXPIRED | pending | on_the_go | status_type | number_of_exchange_activities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 550 |
| 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 320 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 310 |

Comment: If statuses are mutually exclusive, you can do `expired+pending+on_the_go as status_type`

Comment: good answer thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the long form of `case` that allows you to place full conditions in each `when` clause:

```sql
SELECT   expired, pending, on_the_go,
         CASE WHEN expired = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN pending = 2 THEN 2
              WHEN on_the_go = 3 THEN 3
         END AS status_type,
         COUNT(*) AS number_of_exchange_activities 
FROM     card 
GROUP BY expired, pending, on_the_go
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CASE  
    WHEN EXPIRED = 1 THEN 1 
    WHEN pending = 2 THEN 2 
    WHEN on_the_go = 3 THEN 3 
    ELSE 0
END As 'status_type'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about your code. Press [edit] and update your answer.